# Python: Json encode a nested data structure with namedtuples, dates

Tags: python, datetime, json, namedtuple

I have a nested Python data structure with datetime.datetime objects and namedtuples along the following lines:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta
from collections import namedtuple
nt = namedtuple('n', 'name, contact')
f1 = nt('jules', '1234')
f2 = nt('dan', '5678')
x = [
    [dt.now() + timedelta(minutes=1), f1],
    [dt.now() + timedelta(hours=1), f2],
    ]
```

and an Encoder something like this:

```
import json
class TestEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if hasattr(obj, 'isoformat'):
            return obj.isoformat()
        else:
            return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

`print json.dumps(x, cls=TestEncoder)` outputs:

```
[["2012-06-21T00:48:03.296381", ["jules", "1234"]],
 ["2012-06-21T01:47:03.296423", ["dan", "5678"]]]
```

I'd like to turn the namedtuples into dicts (presumably using the namedtuple `._asdict()` method), to get the following output:

```
[["2012-06-21T00:48:03.296381", {"name":"jules", "contact":"1234"}],
 ["2012-06-21T01:47:03.296423", {"name":"dan", "contact":"5678"}]]
```

How can I preserve the general data structure, but json dump the namedtuples as dicts?

Comment: I've added the line "How can I preserve the general data structure, but json dump the namedtuples as dicts?" at the end of the question to make the question clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After re-reading the docs, this appears to be impossible using the built in `json` lib as the only override mechanism (`default`) only gets called after known types (including tuples)

`simplejson` makes this trivial by giving you a `namedtuple_as_object` flag to `simplejson.dump`

```
simplejson.dumps(x, cls=TestEncoder, namedtuple_as_object=True)
```

Comment: Tried that -- it doesn't work. It returns `[["2012-06-21T01:47:55.539578", ["jules", "1234"]], ["2012-06-21T02:46:55.539622", ["dan", "5678"]]]`... also I think the :objects bit of your 3rd line is incorrect.

Comment: This seems to work with simplejson instead of json on Python 2.7. i.e. `import simplejson as json` allows the code to work as is.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a python module for doing this. It is called `typedload`

The interesting thing is that it goes both ways, so from your json you can go back to python objects just by passing the json and the type.

```
import typedload
typedload.dump(data)
```